# Zookeper, что происходит если сервер потеряет соседей

Tags: apache

Что происходит с сервером и его клиентами в случае если в кластере zookeeper один из серверов потерял соседей - он продолжает отдавать те данные которые были на момент потери подключения (как etcd), отключает всех своих клиентов, продолжает отдавать данные за исключением эфемерных нод или что-то еще?

Контекст вопроса: надо иметь доступ к актуальным данным. Если это невозможно - вовремя узнать что доступа нет и выключиться.
В кластере etcd если сервер потерял соединение с общим кластером - он продолжает отдавать данные, но запись в него невозможна. При этом он игнорирует параметр времени жизни значения (ttl), т.е. чтобы определить что данные актуальны каждый клиент должен постоянно писать в сервер и если запись не прошла - переподключаться к другому (вручную, встроенного механизма нет).
Как это устроено в zookeeper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Исходя из [этого обсуждения](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Storage-Random-Access-HDFS/Behavior-of-3-node-Zookeeper-quorum-when-1-node-fails/td-p/16616), [этой страницы](https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ZooKeeper/FailureScenarios) и общепринятого использования модели кворума - та часть кластера, которая не можнт набрать кворум, переходит в waiting state, в котором перестает принимать клиентов и только лишь ждет восстановления кворума:

> As a result, no clients can connect to the ZK service anymore, for
>   reads or for writes. Clients will simply receive a ECONNREFUSED
>   failure at this point. There's no 'read-only' mode - every operation
>   in ZK requires a presence of an quorum. The ZK overview doc mentions
>   this implicitly
>   http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh5/cdh/5/zookeeper/zookeeperOver.html:
>
> """
>   As long as a majority of the servers are available, the ZooKeeper
>   service will be available.
>   """